git repository not found when publishing or cloning
Why does it keeps saying repository not found either when publishing a new repo from vscode or create one from repo and try to clone it?
Logged out and logged back in and it prompts me with sign in but still the same, repo not found not sure what this means exactly.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Thanks. I was able to get that done by removing the entry stored on Manage your credentials section from User Accounts.

Just solved this folds, on Windows you need to go to User Accounts from Control Panel, click Manage your credentials and find the github entry and delete it.
